# Custom View key value coding-compliant

Tags: uiview

I am trying to create a custom view. I know a lot of questions have been ask about it, but none help me.
So I created a CustomView with a single button like this  :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NavigationBar : UIView
{
    IBOutlet UIButton* menu;
}

@end
```

and I am calling the customView like this :

```
UIView* test = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"test" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

but when I call this I am getting the following error :
**this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key menu**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmNiB.png
and i did link my button menu with my file
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilCeN.png

I dont know what I am missing. Plz could you help me with this?

Comment: You probably deleted or changed a property in your source code and didn't update the nib file, so the nib file is pointing to a property that no longer exists.

Comment: The only property the nib file is pointing is the menu one. And it s still in my code.